# Custom taxonomy and custom post type - wrong permalinks and template

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, templates

so here is the deal - I've got a CPT called opencourses. It has some permalink structure, lets say: open-courses. Recently I've decided to add here a custom taxonomy as well. Im doing it via this code:

```
// Register Custom Taxonomy
function custom_taxonomy_blocks() {

    $labels = array(
        'name'                       => _x( 'Bloki szkoleniowe', 'Taxonomy General Name', 'lean' ),
        'singular_name'              => _x( 'Blok szkoleniowy', 'Taxonomy Singular Name', 'lean' ),
        'menu_name'                  => __( 'Blok szkoleniowy', 'lean' ),
        'all_items'                  => __( 'Wszystkie bloki', 'lean' ),
        'parent_item'                => __( 'Element nadrzędny', 'lean' ),
        'parent_item_colon'          => __( 'Element nadrzędny:', 'lean' ),
        'new_item_name'              => __( 'Nazwa nowego bloku', 'lean' ),
        'add_new_item'               => __( 'Dodaj nowy blok', 'lean' ),
        'edit_item'                  => __( 'Edytuj blok', 'lean' ),
        'update_item'                => __( 'Aktualizuj blok', 'lean' ),
        'view_item'                  => __( 'Zobacz blok', 'lean' ),
        'separate_items_with_commas' => __( 'Separate items with commas', 'lean' ),
        'add_or_remove_items'        => __( 'Add or remove items', 'lean' ),
        'choose_from_most_used'      => __( 'Choose from the most used', 'lean' ),
        'popular_items'              => __( 'Popular Items', 'lean' ),
        'search_items'               => __( 'Search Items', 'lean' ),
        'not_found'                  => __( 'Not Found', 'lean' ),
        'no_terms'                   => __( 'No items', 'lean' ),
        'items_list'                 => __( 'Items list', 'lean' ),
        'items_list_navigation'      => __( 'Items list navigation', 'lean' ),
    );
    $rewrite = array(
        'slug'                       => 'blok-szkoleniowy',
        'with_front'                 => true,
        'hierarchical'               => true,
    );
    $args = array(
        'labels'                     => $labels,
        'hierarchical'               => true,
        'public'                     => true,
        'show_ui'                    => true,
        'show_admin_column'          => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'          => true,
        'show_tagcloud'              => true,
        'rewrite'                    => $rewrite,
    );
    register_taxonomy( 'blok-szkoleniowy', array( 'opencourses' ), $args );

}
add_action( 'init', 'custom_taxonomy_blocks', 0 );
```

And it works yet not as I assumed. These are my biggest pain points:

- if cpt permalink is like: /open-courses, then i expect to work the taxonomy like within categories -> so the url will be like: /open-courses/taxonomy/nested-item-in-taxonomy etc. But it doesn't. It simply generates permalink like /taxonomy. How to fix that?
- Somehow the template for the custom post type doesnt work for the view of the taxonomy. How to define/fix that?